# Showing a Text layer for a short amount of time

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

i've got a player and an enemy. When i rightclick the enemy his HP goes down and a hitcounter goes up. I want to make it like when you hit the enemy the text label becomes visible and when you stop attacking it stays visible for a couple more seconds and then hides and sets the hitcounter back to 0.

This is what i have at the moment.

```
public Text GUIHit;
public int HitCounter = 0;

void OnMouseOver()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
    {
        HitCounter++;
        StartCoroutine(ShowHitCounter(HitCounter.ToString(), 2));
    }
}

IEnumerator ShowHitCounter(string message, float delay)
{
    GUIHit.text = message;
    GUIHit.enabled = true;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
    HitCounter = 0;
    GUIHit.enabled = false;
}
```

What happens is that it works for 2 seconds, but even when im still attacking it goes invisible and the hit counter goes back to 0, the coroutine does not get reset back to a starting point.

Comment: use Invoke for such timers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets analyze your code:

```
void OnMouseOver()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1)) //you get passed that if when you hit first time
    {
        HitCounter++;
        StartCoroutine(ShowHitCounter(HitCounter.ToString(), 2)); //you call your label with delay of 2 sec
    }
}

IEnumerator ShowHitCounter(string message, float delay)
{
    GUIHit.text = message;
    GUIHit.enabled = true;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay); // still on your first hit you get to here and wait 2 seconds
    HitCounter = 0; //after 2 seconds you reset hitcounter and disable label
    GUIHit.enabled = false;
}
```

To fix it you need to know when you stopped hitting, and then reset hitcounter and disable label.

I would change showhitcounter to below:

```
IEnumerator ShowHitCounter(string message)
{
    GUIHit.text = message;
    GUIHit.enabled = true;
}
void ClearLabel()
{
    HitCounter = 0; 
    GUIHit.enabled = false;
}
```

}
I made clearLabel to have separate method that clears label. Your logic will have to be in different places and call this method.

One place would onmouseleave event.
Other place would be in your onmouseover and added a property

```
public static DateTime TimeLeft { get; set; }

void OnMouseOver()
{
    TimeSpan span = DateTime.Now - TimeLeft;
    int ms = (int)span.TotalMilliseconds;
    if (ms > 2000)
    {
        ClearLabel();
    }
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1)) 
    {
        HitCounter++;
        StartCoroutine(ShowHitCounter(HitCounter.ToString(), 2)); 
    }
}
```

Also you need to initialize `TimeLeft` somewhere before

Comment: Setting `TimeLeft = DateTime.Now` in `if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))` and adding `yield return null` in `IEnumerator ShowHitCounter(string message)` made it all work, thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

Just finished with my solution and realized there is an answer already. Can't discard it. Just putting it as a solution with **no** memory allocation.

You **don't** need to start Coroutine each time right mouse is clicked like you did in the code in your question. I say this because of constant memory allocation when `StartCoroutine()` is called after each mouse click. Timer in the code below is based on frame-rate but can be easily changed to real-time by using `DateTime.Now`. You can also put the code in a while loop in a Coroutine then call it **once** from Start function.

```
public Text GUIHit;
public int HitCounter = 0;
bool firstRun = true;

float waitTimeBeforeDisabling = 2f;
float timer = 0;

void Update()
{
    //Check when Button is Pressed
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
    {
        //Reset Timer each time  there is a right click
        timer = 0;

        if (!firstRun)
        {
            firstRun = true;
            GUIHit.enabled = true;
        }

        HitCounter++;
        GUIHit.text = HitCounter.ToString();
    }

    //Button is not pressed
    else
    {
        //Increement timer if Button is not pressed and timer < waitTimeBeforeDisabling
        if (timer < waitTimeBeforeDisabling)
        {
            timer += Time.deltaTime;
        }

        //Timer has reached value to Disable Text
        else
        {
            if (firstRun)
            {
                firstRun = false;
                GUIHit.text = HitCounter.ToString();
                HitCounter = 0;
                GUIHit.enabled = false;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Awh, okay then, here's another concept, just for the sake of it :)
Did not test it and such so handle with care, but the thing is, starting a coroutine, etc looks too much (and too expensive) for me for something as little as what you want.

```
private float holdOutTime = 2.0f;
private float lastHitTime = 0.0f;

void OnMouseOver() {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1)) { IncHitAndShowUI() } //compacted
}

private void Update() {
    if (GUIHit.enabled) { TestAndDisableHitUI(); } //compacted
}

#region priv/helper methods
//would force it inline if it was possible in Unity :)
private void IncHitAndShowUI() {
    HitCounter++;
    lastHitTime = Time.time;
    GUIHit.text = HitCounter.ToString();
    GUIHit.enabled = true;
}
//same here :)
private void TestAndDisableHitUI() {
    if (lastHitTime + holdOutTime >= Time.time) {
       GUIHit.enabled = false;
    }
}
#endregion
```